# Enable internationalization for class level constraint validator with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring JPA, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS, Hibernate validator. 
I created my own constraint validator.

The annotation:

```
    Target({ java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE, java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { TicketBundleValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface ValidTicketBundle {

    String message() default "{server.validators.annotations.ValidTicketBundle.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

The validator:

```
public class TicketBundleValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidTicketBundle, TicketBundle> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidTicketBundle constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(TicketBundle value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null)
            return true;

        // Must be at least 1 row for each ticket bundle
        if (value.getRows().size() == 0)
            return false;

        // The start/end date must be valid
        if (value.getStartDate().isAfter(value.getEndDate()))
            return false;

        // The sum of payments can't be greater than the total price of the ticket
        // bundle
        if (value.getTotalPaymentsAmount().compareTo(value.getTotalPrice()) == 1)
            return false;

        // if ( !isValid ) {
        // constraintContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        // constraintContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
        // "{org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter06." +
        // "constraintvalidatorcontext.CheckCase.message}"
        // )
        // .addConstraintViolation();
        // }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I put my key and text both in resources/i18n/messages.properties and resources/i18n/validation.properties:

```
server.validators.annotations.ValidTicketBundle.message = I dati inseriti non sono validi. Verificare nuovamente e ripetere l'operazione.
```

I created my test case to verify if everything is working:

```
 @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void saveTicketBundleWithWrongDateThrowsException() {
        TicketBundle ticketBundle = new TicketBundle();
        ticketBundle.setCustomer(customer);
        ticketBundle.setStartDate(Instant.now().plus(30, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
        ticketBundle.setEndDate(Instant.now());

        Set<ConstraintViolation<TicketBundle>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(ticketBundle);
        assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
        ConstraintViolation<TicketBundle> constraintViolation = constraintViolations.iterator().next();
        assertEquals("I dati inseriti non sono validi. Verificare nuovamente e ripetere l'operazione.",
                constraintViolation.getMessage());
    }
```

but I've a fail because seems the validation key message is not resolved:

```
 org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[I dati inseriti non sono validi. Verificare nuovamente e ripetere l'operazione.]> but was:<[{server.validators.annotations.ValidTicketBundle.message}]>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
```

I'm sure I missed something but it's not very clear what. This is a MVC application but I don't want just the REST endopoint replies with localized message: I expect also the test case receive the right message.

To complete the picture, I've this configuration class in my project:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = { HypermediaType.HAL })
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 @Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    return new SmartLocaleResolver();
}

public class SmartLocaleResolver extends CookieLocaleResolver {
    @Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String acceptLanguage = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        if (acceptLanguage == null || acceptLanguage.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return super.determineDefaultLocale(request);
        }
        return request.getLocale();
    }
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/i18n/messages");
    // messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds((int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1));
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: How message source is referenced in this context?

Comment: @RomanC I thought was automatically referenced by Spring Boot.

Comment: Hey @drenda I have asked you a question? If you can't answer this question you should provide a *clear problem statement* including the code to be able to reproduce the issue, without clear statement and qualified code question is off-topic and should be removed as soon as impossible to give you a solution without knowing details or just remove your post to not disturb developers trying to argue instead of providing details.

Comment: @RomanC Like Message source is not referenced in this context to respond duly to your question. But instead to ask to remove a well documented question, you can simply avoid to reply and let space to other users that know how to reply. The question could be useful for other user having the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in my code. I was wrong, hibernate validator look for the message string into root folder `validationmessages.properties` (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#section-message-interpolation)

I set the message there and everything worked.